# What should I do if packaging design client promises to pay only when he receives the sample prints from his vendor?

Tags: client-relations, freelance, packaging

I am working on a packaging design project. I have already delivered the print ready files to the client and to the vendor hired by the client for the printing. However the client is promising me to pay only when he receives the sample prints from the vendor. The vendor is taking more time than what he had estimated to deliver the sample prints. Even though it's clearly written on our service agreement that client will make the payment at the time of handover of the files. What should I do in such situation?

Comment: Well if you have a written agreement it seems like you have the law on your side. In my country (Denmark), it's customary to have a 14 days payment deadline, but of course if delivery is delayed, it doesn't help much. This question is really a *legal* question and not  really something we are able to answer here. I'm voting to close the question, sorry. Perhaps try https://law.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This sounds like something you should be asking your lawyer.

Comment: Point your client to the agreement. That may resolve the matter entirely. If not .... then either wait.... or consult an attorney .. or sue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your "contract" (service agreement ?) stipulates payment upon hand off of files. This seems clear (at least in your mind) from what you have posted.

If the client is now trying to change that agreement then it seems your only recourse is through legal channels. So, consult an attorney- which is probably going to cause more difficulty in getting paid (and cost money).

Bottom line seems to be- you either need to wait to get paid or negotiate with your client a solution or get an attorney involved. That is pretty much all anyone here can tell you.

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine has an expression - lawyers are like nuclear bombs...everybody wants one but once you use them, it f**ks everything up. So lawyers I think are a last result at the moment.

What is your relationship to this client? First job or ongoing?

How did you meet this client? If recommended to you, can that person intervene?

Have you resent a copy of the contract to the client, with the payment clause highlighted?

Next to last suggestion - offer a 10% discount if paid in full within the next 7 days.

Last suggestion - approach a lawyer on a consult basis only. They may offer some time at no charge to let you know what your options are. But keep in mind they're the nuclear option in time and money if you hire them to solve your problem

I'd also suggest, in the future, for a new client, to ask for a payment percentage up front, with the stipulation that no final files will be released until full payment is made. You can assure them this is just for the first job and will establish credit with your company. If they refuse, walk away.

Comment: I would **never** offer a discount to a client who is delinquent in payment as stipulated in a contract. Reward the client for failure to adhere to a contract???? *That's simply bad business*. Nor would I place any onus on the possible referral person to do **anything** in relation the business doings between myself and the client. A recommendation is one thing, asking someone to "take sides in a dispute" is an entirely undesirable position for most. You can be certain they will *never* recommend you again knowing you expect them to negotiate matters for you if there's a problem.

Comment: A discount to have an invoice paid promptly is not a reward but an incentive. It's very commonly used in the print and paper industry and is often preprinted on every invoice offered for payment. In this case it's an incentive to be paid by what is turning out to be a dishonest client. The idea is to get paid without confrontation.  As far as contacting the referring party party,if they are already know to the designer, this might give the designer more insight into why the payment is delayed. The client is either habitually a late payer or might be under financial stress or both.

Comment: Incentive sure.. but not *after* the client has expressed an unwillingness to adhere to an agreement.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing work and **then** expect payment, you will always **take the risk** of the payment getting delayed or conditioned. Instead, learn to charge some **upfront payment** on your next job. And learn when you should be saying **no**. This is a major client service approach, which is usually overlooked when starting out.

On this particular case, hopefully the work is good, in which case the client should get good sample prints, in which case you can probably assume that you will actually get the payment.

Comment: The "money upfront" principle does not apply in all cultures though. Here in Denmark it's not common practice (high level of trust?) and would scare some clients away. Except of course when we talk about a lot of money and there are subcontractors involved who wants money upfront for materials for example.

Comment: True, I have nordic clients as well, and know what you're talking about. But I have clients from everywhere, and in other countries, western/US included, clients don't always feel they have an obligation to pay, unless the work is really like, blowing their socks off. Or, unless a contract exists and a downpayment has been made prior. I must admit I have come across clients with this particular attitude, in my early days, and definitely not nordic clients. Even when the work is really good and on brand, there is always the risk of the work being rejected, even without a reason.